# How to get the base URL of a site

Tags: 8, uri

My site is on http://drupal8.local/. How do I get the *drupal8.local* part of that URL?

`Url::fromRoute('<'current'>')` or `base_path()` returns the path parth of the URL; For example, for http://drupal8.local/a/b/c/d/e/f, they return '`/a/b/c/d/e/f'` when I just need to get `'drupal8.local'`.

How can I get that part of the URL?

Comment: Do you actually mean hostname or base URL?  The base URL can include path portions when Drupal isn't run in the root directory.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can get the hostname, "drupal8.local", directly from the [`getHost()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetHost/8.2.x) request:

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
```

In some cases you might want to get the schema as well, fx `https://drupal8.local`:

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Comment: Note: `\Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()` will return `http://drupal8.local`.

Comment: Note if your site is on a subpath (e.g. your homepage is on http://drupal8.local/uk), this will not return the subpath.  To do this you can use `Url::fromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);`

Comment: Upvoting comments from leon.nk.  Url is going to get you the sub directory and any port if you are on a non-standard port.  And, Url is replaced by urlGenerator.  Updated code is: \Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);

Comment: Running this from Drush (version 8) this will give a result : Default.

Comment: Correct @Justme - drush is a command line tool so naturally there’s no http host

Comment: @Clive – Why not simply `global $base_url`?

Comment: Just habit @leymannx - I prefer to get request data from the request rather than rely on globals (I'm not a fan of global vars at all to be honest)

Comment: Really my head is smoking trying to get your answer to work with both use cases: 1. site lives in subdir, 2. language prefix exists. Which can just be solved with one line of code: `global $base_url`...

Comment: Language prefix isn't part of the hostname @leymannx, that's part of the URL. Yes if you're in a subdir you might need to adjust

Comment: @leon.nk On a subpath you can also use `\Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . base_path()`

Answer (score 10):

There are some warnings about directly accessing the request object in this way in `\Drupal::request`:

```
 * Note: The use of this wrapper in particular is especially discouraged. Most
 * code should not need to access the request directly.  Doing so means it
 * will only function when handling an HTTP request, and will require special
 * modification or wrapping when run from a command line tool, from certain
 * queue processors, or from automated tests.
 *
 * If code must access the request, it is considerably better to register
 * an object with the Service Container and give it a setRequest() method
 * that is configured to run when the service is created.  That way, the
 * correct request object can always be provided by the container and the
 * service can still be unit tested.
```

Any form controller extending `\Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase` automatically has this dependency injected, and it may be accessed using:

```
$this->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```

I think (but haven't tested) that a regular page controller extending `\Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase` could provide the `request_stack` service by overriding the `\Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase::create` function, and then setting a `$request` property in the constructor. This is described really well for forms, and the same process should apply for page controllers: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to do this with dependency injection and a service, then you can use [RequestStack](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3ArequestStack/8.2.x):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
```

And define it like this:

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(..., RequestStack $request_stack) {
  ...
  $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, ...) {
  return new static(
    ...
    $container->get('request_stack')
  )
}
```

And then declare it like this:

```
$this->request->getHost()
$this->request->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```

Answer (score 9):

Taking into account the "*warnings about directly accessing the request object in this way in \Drupal::request*" that *Shaun Dychko* mentioned, perhaps a good option to get the hostname is obtain it from the *$base_url* global variable, with the help of php function *parse_url*:

```
global $base_url;
$base_url_parts = parse_url($base_url);
$host = $base_url_parts['host'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Code below is how core defines the `[site:url]` token. This works best in all cases for me in drupal 8 & 9:

```
$url_options = [
  'absolute' => TRUE,
  'language' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(),
];
$site_url = Url::fromRoute('<front>', [], $url_options)->toString();
```

Comment: This adds language prefix if present, like 'drupal8.local/en/'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/', ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\Drupal::request()->getBaseUrl()
```