# Register an object with the Service Container and give it a setRequest() (get base url)

Tags: 8, uri

I'm looking for a way to get the hostname of a multisite, and I've found several answers about it.

One of the solutions was to use:
[Answer link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202811/57858)

```
$host= \Drupal::request()->getHost();
```

or

```
\Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Per also a user comments that the use of the Request object can be dangerous, as mentioned in the [following link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/235545/57858).

The comment warning say: [Url to documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x)

> Note: The use of this wrapper in particular is especially discouraged.
>   Most code should not need to access the request directly. Doing so
>   means it will only function when handling an HTTP request, and will
>   require special modification or wrapping when run from a command line
>   tool, from certain queue processors, or from automated tests.
>
> If code must access the request, it is considerably better to register
>   an object with the Service Container and give it a setRequest() method
>   that is configured to run when the service is created. That way, the
>   correct request object can always be provided by the container and the
>   service can still be unit tested.
>
> If this method must be used, never save the request object that is
>   returned. Doing so may lead to inconsistencies as the request object
>   is volatile and may change at various times, such as during a
>   subrequest.

I have a custom module and I have a service, is it possible to implement it in a service?

My question is according to the comment and recommendation of the API, how is it that it should be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: The `ViewExecutable` class follows that pattern. The factory service (`ViewExecutableFactory`) instantiates a View object based on the current HTTP request (from the injected request_stack service), and passes it through to the View. I would go with that approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example (extracted from real code I just wrote in for Drupal 10.1) of getting the current request from the `request_stack` service in a plugin. Another service would just be wired into your `module.services.yml` instead of using the `create()` method:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\MyPlugin;

use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MyPlugin extends implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * Resoruce Manager service.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack,
                              array $configuration,
                              $plugin_id,
                              $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('request_stack'),
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition
    );
  }

  function doSomething() {
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    ...
  }

}
```

And here's the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html) that basically says the same thing.