# Can I get the absolute path to the frontpage in theme_preprocess_html?

Tags: 8, hooks

Is it possible to get the absolute path to the homepage or `<front>` eg: `https://www.domain.com/homepage` in the `theme_preprocess_html` hook? I tried `global $base_url` but it throws an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the base URL of a site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202810/how-to-get-the-base-url-of-a-site)

Comment: `global $base_url;`

Comment: Hello again @leymannx :) `global $base_url` throws an error. 

I got the absolute path with this though: `\Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);` which is in the duplicate question you posted but hidden in one of the comments.

Comment: Hey hey, what error?

Comment: Error: `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL) in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() `

Comment: Sounds like a simple typo. I'd need to see the whole snippet to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `\Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);` from one of the comments in:

[How to get the base URL of a site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202810/how-to-get-the-base-url-of-a-site)

Here is the entire working snippet:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  // Modify if we're on nodes
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    // Get the node-type
    $nodetype = $node->getType();
    // Switch class for node-type
    switch ($nodetype) {
      case "landing":
        // prefetch frontpage from landing pages
        $frontpage_path = \Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
        $prefetchfront = [
          '#tag' => 'link',
          '#attributes' => [
            'rel' => 'prefetch prerender',
            'href' => $frontpage_path,
          ],
        ];
        $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$prefetchfront, 'prefetch'];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't generate the url at this point, only create a url data object and let the render engine do the rest: `Url::fromRoute('<'front'>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]) `

Comment: Gives error: `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'front' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() `

Comment: It probably should be `'<front>'` in @4k4's comment.

Comment: Yes, @leymannx, the route name has a typo. The point is to use `\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute()` instead of [UrlGeneratorInterface::generateFromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorInterface.php/function/UrlGeneratorInterface%3A%3AgenerateFromRoute/8.6.x), which is marked as internal and shouldn't be used in user code.

Comment: Kris, would you mind updating your answer incorporating these infos?

Comment: Will post my snippet that works, maybe there's a reason why your two options don't.

Comment: Yes, because there were typos. As @4k4 already mentioned you are not supposed to use an internal function for that.

Comment: @KrisRobinson, now after seeing the code snippet I would suggest: `Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute()->toString()`

Comment: @4k4 is `Url::fromRoute` dependent of `use Drupal\Core\Url;`?

Comment: Yes, this use statement or the fully qualified class name mentioned before.